# VBA - 2D Array of Objects where Dimension 1 different Custom Object Type from Dimension 2

Tags: arrays, vba, object

In a VBA macro I am looking to create a 2D array of Objects, where the first dimension is a different custom object type from the second dimension.

I have the Class Modules "Work Request" and "Component". A work request can contain several components, thus the need for a 2D array.

If a 1D array of objects is declared as:

```
Dim ActiveWorkRequests(10) As WorkRequest
```

I'm hoping for something following the logic of:

```
Dim ActiveWorkRequests(10, 10) As WorkRequest, Component
```

Thank you for your time and insights.

Comment: so a 2d array is similar to a worksheet with the first as the rows and second as the columns, so how do you see this working?  The first column is workrequest and the rest component?  Or are you envisioning two columns one that is workrequest and the other component?

Comment: If you imagine `AcitveWorkRequests(10,10)` as a 10x10 grid then where would your `WorkRequest` objects and `Components` go in that grid? It doesn't really make much sense to me. If `WorkRequest` was a container holding 10 components then it would make sense to fill `ActiveWorkRequests(10)` with your 10 `WorkRequest` objects

Comment: @ScottCraner - I'm envisioning the first column as a WorkRequest, and the rest as Components (e.g.: WR1, C1, C2, C3, C4 /nextrow/ WR2, C1, C2, etc).

Comment: @CallumDA - you're helping me clarify my understanding of how to accomplish the link between the components and their corresponding work requests. I'll implement a 1D array of WorkRequests and a 2D array of Components. The array sizes will be the same so position i in arrayComponents will always reference the appropriate index in arrayWorkRequests.

Answer (score 1):

Using classes is good, but you then need to know the best way to access them.

Here's how I'd do it.

**Component**

First, create your `Component` class. This is a simple class with just a `Number` property which can be accessed and written to (hence the `Get` and `Let`)

```
Option Explicit

Private pNumber As Long

Public Property Get Number() As Long
    Number = pNumber
End Property

Public Property Let Number(ByVal Value As Long)
    pNumber = Value
End Property
```

**WorkRequest**

Then create your `WorkRequest` class. The work request holds 10 components, and when I create the components I give them a number (at random). I have one `Property` which allows me to `Get` a `Component` from the `WorkRequest`

```
Option Explicit

Private pComponents(1 To 10) As Component

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Component

    For i = 1 To 10
        Set c = New Component
        c.Number = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 100)
        Set pComponents(i) = c
    Next i
End Sub

Public Property Get Component(componentNumber As Long) As Component
    Set Component = pComponents(componentNumber)
End Property
```

> **Standard Module**
>
> Then, finally, in a standard code module you can access the components
>   like this:
>
> ```
> Option Explicit
>
> Sub Test()
>     Dim i As Long
>     Dim wr As WorkRequest
>     Dim ActiveWorkRequests(1 To 10) As WorkRequest
>
>     For i = 1 To 10
>         Set wr = New WorkRequest 'containing 10 components
>         Set ActiveWorkRequests(i) = wr
>     Next i
>
>     Debug.Print ActiveWorkRequests(5).Component(9).Number
> End Sub
> ```
>
> In this example I have used
>   `ActiveWorkRequests(5).Component(9).Number` but it could have been
>   anything from `..(1)..(1)` to `..(10)..(10)`

---

As expected, this is the output in the Immediate Window:

```
 67 
 43 
 29 
 65 
 20
```

These are the random numbers that we assigned to the `Component` objects when we created the `WorkRequest` objects.

Comment: @HerbalTea, happy to help :) did that all make sense?